# View is not getting notified when value of static Property Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ViewModelBase class as follows:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler GlobalPropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public static void OnGlobalPropertyChanged(string propertyName, Type className)
    {
        GlobalPropertyChanged(className,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now, I have another viewModel called GroupViewModel which inherits ViewModelBase:

```
public class GroupViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public GroupsViewModel()
    {
        CurrentGroup = new Group();
    }

    private static Group _currentGroup;
    public static Group CurrentGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentGroup = value;
            OnGlobalPropertyChanged("CurrentGroup", typeof(Group));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in Groups.xaml Page :

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentGroup}">
    .....
    .....
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName, TargetNullValue=''}" />
    .....
    .....
</Grid>
```

I have another ViewModel called MainWindowViewModel, I try to save CurrentGroup to Database like below code and then I set `CurrentGroup = new Group();` but in Group.xaml the text of TextBox is not cleared :

```
Group group = GroupViewModel.CurrentGroup;
db.Groups.Add(group);
db.SaveChanges();
GroupViewModel.CurrentGroup = new Group();
```

**Update:**

If I use the below code in GroupsViewModel, the output is as expected. I mean View is updated when Static property changes.

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
         = delegate { };
private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

If I use that same code in ViewModelBase (Please note that GroupsViewModel inherits ViewModelBase) then View is not updated when value of static property changes. Also I have marked the NotifyStaticPropertyChanged as public in this case to avoid the compile time errors like errors about protection level.

Comment: Try solution provided [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties).

Comment: The property changed event of the viewmodel had to be raised, static members are not members of the instance.

Comment: @RohitVats OK I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @Silvermind what do you mean by The property changed event of the viewmodel had to be raised?

Comment: @RohitVats I cannot open the link you provided. It just keeps on Loading.......

Comment: Typo: I meant 'has'. You would need to raise the event that is associated with the instance.

Comment: It works at my end. Try this - http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties.

Comment: @RohitVats still same problem.

Comment: @Silvermind I don't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Vishal - I have converted that into an answer. Please check.

Comment: It is exactly as Rohit Vats explains in his answer, he is binding to the static *instance* of the class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `Static PropertyChanged` you have to create generic static event like this in your class:

```
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
         = delegate { };
private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

and you have to call like you use to do instance properties:

```
NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("CurrentGroup");
```

But main catch is in XAML where you are binding -

> You'll use parentheses around the namespace, class, and property
>   because WPF binding engine parse the path as ClassName.PropertyName
>   rather than PropertyName.PropertyName.

So, it will be like this:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=(local:GroupViewModel.CurrentGroup)}">
  .....
  .....
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupName, TargetNullValue=''}" />
  .....
  .....
</Grid>
```

Source here [INPC for static properties](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/11/29/wpf-45-binding-and-change-notification-for-static-properties).

---

**UPDATE**

> If I use that same code in ViewModelBase (Please note that
>   GroupsViewModel inherits ViewModelBase) then View is not updated when
>   value of static property changes.

**`StaticPropertyChangedEvent` have to be in same class where property resides**. It won't work like traditional `INotifyPropertyChanged` for instance properties.

I don't have any MSDN documentation to assert that but I verified it by tweaking event code a bit to see if XAML is hooking onto `StaticPropertyChangedEvent` from XAML.

Replace event code to this and you can see yourself:

```
private static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> staticPC
                                                     = delegate { };
public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged
{
   add { staticPC += value; }
   remove { staticPC -= value; }
}
protected static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
   staticPC(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Put a breakpoint on add and you will see it will get hit since WPF binding engine internally hook to it to listen to static property changed events.

But as soon as you move that to base class ViewModelBase, breakpoint won't get hit. Since, WPF haven't hook to it so any changes in property won't update UI obviously.

Comment: I have tried to use the above example but in xaml I get the following error : `Nested Types are not supported : GroupViewModel.CurrentGroup`. Also, In my question I missed to show some information. My Page's DataContext is local:GroupViewModel, Then as you can see in qustion Grid's DataContext is set to CurrentGroup and Text of textBox is bound to GroupName. Isn't it the same thing that you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: You are confusing static with instance properties. DataContext is set to an instance of `GroupViewModel` but property is static so you can't access it with instance object which is valid for XAML as well. You have to set DataContext like i did in my updated answer. If there are other items in Grid, simply move that DataContext onto TextBlock and you are done.

Comment: Now I don't get any errors but the behavior is still same. I mean my textBox is still not clearing up.

Comment: I tried it in small app and working fine at my end. Can you try this in small app or let me know atleast exact steps to produce it?

Comment: you can find demo project here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bUW1HVk9mWjIzVk0/edit?usp=sharing but I am getting an error in that project : Key cannot be null. Parameter name key.

Comment: I have uploaded a small demo where this is working. Validate against it what you are missing in your code. Link can be found here - http://1drv.ms/1ewwvdT. Download StaticPropertyChangeDemo from the link.

Comment: I think I have some problems with my internet connection. I cannot open the link you provided above. The page keeps loading and at last it says the webpage is not available. I have tried to open it in Internet Explorer as well as Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you share mail id? I will send the zip file across.

Comment: vishalsherathiya@gmail.com

Comment: I have sent it across. See if that helps.

Comment: I have tried your demo. It works perfectly. I have done same thing and it works for me as well. But I get some problems. Please see Update part in my question.

Comment: OK, then I will use it on all ViewModels where I need Static Property Changed. Thanks for great help.

Comment: Glad to help Vishal.. :)

Comment: Using parentheses instead of {x:Static} was the only change required in my case, I am binding to a static ObservableCollection<T>

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to update the property changes of a particular data type, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface *in that data type*. This means that if you want to update the property changes of a view model, in your case a change to the `CurrentGroup` object, you'd need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface *in your view model*.

However, it seems as though you *actually* want to update the property changes that have been made *inside* the `CurrentGroup` class (to clear them), so in that case, you'd need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `CurrentGroup` class as well. I believe that that is what @Silvermind meant by *You would need to raise the event that is associated with the instance*.