# Static property not updating in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, static, inotifypropertychanged

I spent the last hour(s) trying to find an answer in google and stackoverflow. I followed different advices & suggestions, but nothing worked so far. My current code looks like this:

```
public class GlobalManager : ViewModelBase
{
    static object _LockObject_GFS = new object();
    static double _GlobalFontSize;
    public static double GlobalFontSize
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                _GlobalFontSize = GetGlobalResource<double>(LambdaHelper.MemberToString(() => GlobalFontSize));
                return _GlobalFontSize;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                if (_GlobalFontSize != value)
                {
                    _GlobalFontSize = value;
                    SetGlobalResource(value, LambdaHelper.MemberToString(() => GlobalFontSize));
                    NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(() => GlobalFontSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The getter & setter are both called. `NotifyStaticPropertyChanged` works and my UI does not update. I've added a `TextBlock` to check if it updates. Apparently it does not.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(global:GlobalManager.GlobalFontSize), Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

If I define a property in my VM (current DataContext), and bind it to a `TextBlock`, it updates correctly with the current value.

Currently the `DependencyProperty` `Value` of a `Slider` is bound to this property in order to update the font size. (`IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"`)

```
public double GlobalFontSize
{
    get { return GlobalManager.GlobalFontSize; }
    set { GlobalManager.GlobalFontSize = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => GlobalFontSize); }
}
```

How do I get the binding to work correctly with the static property ? *The `StaticPropertyChanged` event is not null.*

```
StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

---

Edit 1:

```
public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T> > property)
{
    var expr = property.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (expr == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Lambda does not contain member expression. () => MyClassOrObject.Property");
    NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(expr.Member.Name);
}
```

Comment: @mm8 `The StaticPropertyChanged event is not null.` My signature is correct.

Comment: How is your NotifyStaticPropertyChanged method implemented?

Comment: @mm8 Like the "normal" implementation. See my edit.

Comment: I don't like the whole idea about using `static` property and binding. Rather use singleton (`GlobalManager.Instance.GlobalFontSize`), then you can bind to `static` property returning **instance**, which is a normal ViewModel or event Model implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This way rising notification is straighforward and, well, it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your `GetGlobalResource` and `SetGlobalResource` methods work as expected and that your event signature is correct.

You could refer to the below working sample implementation and compare it to yours:

```
public class GlobalManager
{
    static object _LockObject_GFS = new object();
    static double _GlobalFontSize;
    public static double GlobalFontSize
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                return _GlobalFontSize;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                if (_GlobalFontSize != value)
                {
                    _GlobalFontSize = value;
                    NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(()=> GlobalFontSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var expr = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expr == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda does not contain member expression. () => MyClassOrObject.Property");
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(expr.Member.Name);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** It doesn't work if the event is defined in a base class though.

```
public abstract class MyBaseViewModel
{
    public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
    {
        var expr = property.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (expr == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Lambda does not contain member expression. () => MyClassOrObject.Property");
        NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(expr.Member.Name);
    }
}

public class GlobalManager : MyBaseViewModel
{
    static object _LockObject_GFS = new object();
    static double _GlobalFontSize = 10.0;
    public static double GlobalFontSize
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                return _GlobalFontSize;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_LockObject_GFS)
            {
                if (_GlobalFontSize != value)
                {
                    _GlobalFontSize = value;
                    NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("GlobalFontSize");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `StaticPropertyChangedEvent` must be defined in same class where property resides for the binding to get updated:

[View is not getting notified when value of static Property Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346212/view-is-not-getting-notified-when-value-of-static-property-changes)

Comment: `If I define a property in my VM (current DataContext), and bind it to a TextBlock, it updates correctly with the current value.` These Get/Set-GlobalResource methods work. Aside from that, does it make a difference if I have the `StaticPropertyChanged` event in the base class or in the class with the static property itself ?

Comment: "Does it make a difference if I have the StaticPropertyChanged event in the base class or in the class with the static property itself"? Yes, it does.

Comment: Strange but well... I'll keep the classes to a minimum. Thank you.

Comment: Weird, after two days of searching on this issue, this answer solved it, despite looking at many others. Now I have to figure out WHY this worked and the others didnt heh...