# Inherit INotifyPropertyChanged for Static Event from abstract Class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to implement a number of Abstraction Layers for various pieces of hardware, and I've found I've implemented the same function, `NofityStaticPropertyChanged` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111290/2444435)) about 5 times.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// A slightly different implementation of Static Property Changed, from here:
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111290/2444435
    /// </summary>
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    protected static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I'd like to have all of these classes inherit from an `abstract class AbstractionBase` to avoid reusing code.

I've read elsewhere as to how to inherit this sort of function for *non-static* members, but I'm never actually instantiating these abstraction layers/factories.

I'm not sure this is actually possible, since static properties cannot be inherited. I feel like it ought to be though, since it's basically a function, not a property? My current attempt is thus:

```
public abstract class AbstractionBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //THIS IS NOT WORKING!
    #region INofity Declarations
    /// <summary>
    /// A slightly different implementation of Static Property Changed, from here:
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111290/2444435
    /// </summary>
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    protected static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thanks! I have a feeling I might not be able to get away with this de-duplication attempt, but if it is possible, then that'd be nifty!

Comment: Why does the event have to be static? Just remove the static keyword and you have a reusable base class that you can extend.

Comment: Because I'm binding to static properties.

Comment: Yes, the question is why.

Comment: I have been making my Factories static, and just bind the GUI selections directly to them. When I actually Connect to a piece of hardware, the Factory returns an object of the appropriate type. 

I could technically instantiate the Factories, but it seemed like it would be cleaner to leave them static, as they don't do anything other than return objects based on a handful of selection parameters.

Maybe a Singleton pattern would be better for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF 4.5 supports binding to static properties, all you have to do is create a static event handler of the same name with the text "Changed" appended, and you invoke that instead of your StaticPropertyChanged:

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    public static event EventHandler MyStaticPropertyChanged;

    private static string _MyStaticProperty = "Hello World!";
    public static string MyStaticProperty
    {
        get { return _MyStaticProperty; }
        set
        {
            if (_MyStaticProperty != value)
            {
                _MyStaticProperty = value;
                MyStaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which you would bind to like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(vm:MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty), Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Honestly though, this looks like more of an architectural issue to me. If you're using a dependency injection framework...and you should be....then there's absolutely no need to use static properties for anything, just place them in their own class and set up your DI to make it a singleton.

Comment: Yea, that's basically what I'm doing; the static properties I was using are basically the properties required for each Factory to instantiate different types of hardware, which each implement a common Interface for a given Factory. 

I am mostly trying to not copy/paste code between the different Factories; that and I didn't want to actually instantiate them - I am using them as a singleton. Maybe I've just implemented that in a non-ideal way by using static properties.